# Как сделать чтобы ячейка раскрывалась в другом окне objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Как сделать, чтобы ячейка раскрывалась, нужно в NCData.m написать списки, например ячейка Сауда орталықтары должна раскрываться на "ханшатыр", "керуен", "азияпарк" и т.д. Как это сделать?

NCData.m

```
#import "NCData.h"

@implementation NCData

+ (NSArray *)fetchData
{
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

    NCData *item; 

    item = [[NCData alloc] init];
    item.title = @"Сауда орталықтары";
    item.imageName = @"IMG_7038.JPG";
    item.orindar = @"Ханшатыр";
    item.orindar = @"Керуен";

    [result addObject:item];

    item = [[NCData alloc] init];
    item.title = @"Жоғарғы оқу орындары";
    item.imageName = @"IMG_7042.JPG";
    [result addObject:item];

    item = [[NCData alloc] init];
    item.title = @"Қонақ үйлер";
    item.imageName = @"IMG_7020.JPG";
    [result addObject:item];

    item = [[NCData alloc] init];
    item.title = @"Мұражайлар";
    item.imageName = @"IMG_7034.JPG";
    [result addObject:item];

    item = [[NCData alloc] init];
    item.title = @"Мейрамхана";
    item.imageName = @"IMG_7041.JPG";
    [result addObject:item];

    item = [[NCData alloc] init];
    item.title = @"Бизнес орталықтар";
    item.imageName = @"IMG_7037.JPG";
    [result addObject:item];
    return result;
}

@end
```